# Hot to put two ngValue and two ngModel together?

Tags: angular

I'm new at Angular and I want to do something like this:

```
<select class="custom-select ml-3" id="conector" name="conector" [(ngModel)]="activity.conectorType" [(ngModel)]="activity.conectorTypeId">
    <option [disabled]="accion === accions.SHOW" *ngFor="let conector of conectors" name="conector" [ngValue]="conector" [ngValue]="conector.id" >{{conector.name}}</option>
</select>
```

But, when I debbug the code, `[ngValue]="conector.id"` affect both `[(ngModel)]` and I have an error since conectorType is and object and not a number...

Is there any way to make first ngVale affect first `ngModel` and second `ngValue` affect second `ngModel`?

Thank you

Comment: You will have to make the second one a ngModelChange and manually change it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 `ngModel` on a HTML element. Like suggested in the comments, you can do it with the `(ngModelChange)` event, thanks to `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<select 
  class="custom-select ml-3"
  id="conector"
  name="conector"
  [(ngModel)]="activity.conectorType"
  (ngModelChange)="connectorNgModelChange($event)"
>
  <option 
    [disabled]="accion === accions.SHOW"
    *ngFor="let conector of conectors" 
    [ngValue]="conector">{{conector.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In your component ts class:

```
connectorNgModelChange(newValue) {
  // newValue is the value binded to [ngValue] of the selected <option>
  this.activity.connectorTypeId = newValue.id
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!!